# Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code. Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift5, swift-compiler

[image]I'm getting this my countly target and other notification related target. I tried compilation mode to Whole module but it didn't help.

[image: This is issue list.]

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Yummypets/YPImagePicker/issues/236). You can fix it by doing the following:

> Compilation might fail without displaying the errors responsible for the failure. For example, you might see the message “Command
> CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code” without an
> accompanying failure reason. (43033749) Workaround: Disable batch mode
> by adding a user-defined build setting named SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE
> and set it to NO.
>
> [image]
>
> Once you have added the build setting, the real problem will be
> revealed

Comment: i have made the changes but still facing same issue.

Comment: @GaneshShetty Try clearing the project with Command + Shift + K

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: @GaneshShetty Try re-booting your Mac?

Comment: @Danniil the same issue again.